# How do I solve a traceback when runing manage.py commands?

Tags: python, django

I am pretty new to Django and I was just following along witht the tutorial.
I was making a project from https://github.com/justdjango/getting-started-with-django, and after I added users and a superuser, I started to get a Traceback like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\prog\programa\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\__init__.py", line 160, in get_user_model
    return django_apps.get_model(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, require_ready=False)
  File "C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\prog\programa\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 204, in get_model    
    app_label, model_name = app_label.split('.')
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\prog\manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\prog\manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\prog\programa\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 419, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\prog\programa\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\prog\programa\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\prog\programa\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 122, in populate     
    app_config.ready()
  File "C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\prog\programa\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\apps.py", line 27, in ready    
    self.module.autodiscover()
  File "C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\prog\programa\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\__init__.py", line 24, in autodiscover
    autodiscover_modules('admin', register_to=site)
  File "C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\prog\programa\lib\site-packages\django\utils\module_loading.py", line 47, in autodiscover_modules
    import_module('%s.%s' % (app_config.name, module_to_search))
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.2032.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 850, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\prog\programa\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\admin.py", line 6, in <module>  
    from django.contrib.auth.forms import (
  File "C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\prog\programa\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\forms.py", line 21, in <module> 
    UserModel = get_user_model()
  File "C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\prog\programa\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\__init__.py", line 162, in get_user_model
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("AUTH_USER_MODEL must be of the form 'app_label.model_name'")
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: AUTH_USER_MODEL must be of the form 'app_label.model_name'
```

Comment: Can you show the `AUTH_USER_MODEL = ...` line of your `settings.py`?

Comment: `STATIC_URL = '/static/'

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'leads'


# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to specify the *model name* in the `AUTH_USER_MODEL` setting. If you defined a model `User` in the `leads` app, you thus set this with:

```
# settings.py

#           app name ↓
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'leads.User'
#              model name ↑
```

Comment: Document available at : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model